# Using calendars or Joda-Time in java

Tags: java

I have a document that starts on date X and end on date Y and and goes up by one day.  My task is to go through this document and find out how many days are missing from the document.

```
Example:
19990904 56.00
19990905 57.00
19990907 60.00
```

Need to print out that 19900906 is missing.

I have done some research and read about java calendar, Date, and Joda-Time, yet was unable to understand what any of them are.  Can some one please explain what these functions I just mentioned do, and then make a suggestion on how to use one to accomplish my goal?

I already have this code:

```
String name = getFileName();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));

String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{  //while
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String [] holder = line.split(delims);

    // System.out.println("*");

    int date = Integer.parseInt(holder[0]); 
    //System.out.println(holder[0]);

    double price = Double.parseDouble(holder[1]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JodaTime. (If you are only concerned with date, you should NOT use datetimes, or mess with hours,minutes, dst issues.)

```
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");

LocalDate date=null;
while( (line = getNextLine())!=null) {
   String dateAsString = line.split(delims)[0];
   LocalDate founddate = dtf.parseLocalDate(dateAsString);
   if(date==null) { date= founddate; continue;} // first
   if(founddate.before(date)) throw new RuntimeException("date not sorted?");
   if(founddate.equals(date)) continue; // dup dates are ok?
   date = date.plusDays(1);
   while(date.before(foundate)){
       System.out.println("Date not found: " +date);
       date = date.plusDays(1);
   }
}
```

If you only need to count missing days:

```
LocalDate date=null;
int cont=0;
while( (line = getNextLine())!=null) {
   String dateAsString = line.split(delims)[0];
   LocalDate founddate = dtf.parseLocalDate(dateAsString);
   if(date==null) { date= founddate; continue;} // first
   if(founddate.before(date)) throw new RuntimeException("date not sorted?");
   if(founddate.equals(date)) continue; // dup dates are ok?
   cont += Days.daysBetween(date, founddate)-1;
   date = founddate;
}
```

Comment: do I need to import anything to use JodaTime?

Comment: @Danny yeah jodatime itself http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.2

Comment: I' getting errors because of the use of LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter

Answer (score 3):

```
LocalDate x = new LocalDate(dateX); 
LocalDate y = new LocalDate(dateY);

int i = Days.daysBetween(x, y).getDays();

missingdays = originalSizeofList - i;
```

This is joda-time, its much easier than vanilla java.

Comment: +1 for using Joda time for any place where you want to manipulate dates using human readable fields.

Comment: I just updated my question, I did not provide enough information which is my bad.  I am using a buffered reader and discarding the array with each line (file is 20gb) so I don't think this will work :-(

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as the OP wanted every missing day to be printed, not just a count of them.